# Updating a knockout observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Im having some trouble updating a knockout observable value. I need to pass the value from linkClick into showMenu.

When I manually update showMenu like this showMenu("Value"), the Value will get passed to the view fine. It needs to be a dynamic value however. This is essentially my code as it stands.

```
//View
<a data-bind="click: linkClick" data-sec="Value">Click Me</a>

<!-- ko if: showMenu() === 'Value' -->
    <ul class="Menu">
        <li>Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
    </ul>
<!-- /ko -->

define(
  [''],
  function () {
    var _this = this;
    return {

        showMenu: ko.observable(""),
        linkClick: function(data, event) {

            var element = event.target,                    
                Menu = $(element).attr('data-sec');

            var myMenu = this.showMenu();
            this.showMenu(Menu);

        }
    }
});
```

Ive also tried using *_this* in the global scope instead of *this* however this produces a _this.showMenu() is not a function error. Please help.

PS. I have to write everything inside that first function definition.

Comment: Where should the value for showMenu(?) will come from?

Comment: `this` in  `var _this = this;` doesn't point anything (well it actually points the window object I guess). If you write `var _this = { _here_the_litteral_definition_of_some_object_with_methods_ }`, `_this.showMenu()` works. Also, if you're defining a package, one often recommends "exports" instead of _this as a variable name for the module you're defining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `data` (which is your viewmodel) instead of `this`

```js
function vm() {
  return {
    showMenu: ko.observable(""),
    linkClick: function(data, event) {
      var element = event.target,
        Menu = $(element).attr('data-sec');

      // use data instead of this
      data.showMenu(Menu);
    }
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<a data-bind="click: linkClick" data-sec="Value">Click Me</a> 
<!-- ko if: showMenu() === 'Value' -->
<ul class="Menu">
  <li>Link 1</li>
  <li>Link 2</li>
</ul>
<!-- /ko -->
```